# Android Mobile App Not Loading Webview on Startup

Tags: android, webview, mobile-application

I am seeing a new issue pop up in my Mobile App for only Android users. When the app is launched, it directs the users to a webview login page. Currently, it shows the loading spinner that displays when waiting to connect to the site, but it never does.. giving me an infinite loading spinner.

In the test environment, this does not occur. Even when using a prod build, if I leave the app unsigned, it will still work. Once I sign it, the app again does not load.

I have tried updating Chrome and Android Webview system app, as it seems a few months ago a similar thing was happening to some Google apps. I have also messed around with some of the minified files, edited the proguard file, updated react-native-webview, tried a newer build template for the tool I am using... nothing seems to be working.

Does anyone have any other suggestions I could try?

Comment: You can debug the WebView using Google Chrome Developer Tools. Enter `chrome://inspect/#devices` into the address bar and select Inspect for the WebView you want to debug.